# Send Form Value to Modal

Tags: php, sql, modal-dialog

I have a form that asks for 3 fields. Once the form is submitted, it should open a modal. In the modal a budget summary should show. The budget summary data is pulled from a database and the values are based on the 3 form fields entered. I can't seem to get the values to show up in the modal so the query will work but, the modal does open.

Here is the modal code:

```
    <!-- Large modal -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" id="myLargeModalLabel" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content p-4">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Budget Summary</h4>For Account: <?php echo $account; ?>, Fund: <?php echo $_POST['fund2']; ?>, DeptID#: <?php echo $deptID; ?><br><em>The budgeted balance is an estimate.</em></h4>
      <br>  <?php if ($budget_summary->TotalRows == 0) { // Show if mysqli recordset empty ?>There is no data. Please try your search again.<?php } ?>
        <?php if ($budget_summary->TotalRows > 0) { // Show if mysqli recordset empty ?><table width="100%" class="table table-responsive" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="6" class="display" id="example2">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Budgeted Amount</th>
                 <th align="left" valign="top">Budgeted Balance</th>
                 <th align="left" valign="top">Program</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
while(!$budget_summary->atEnd()) {
?><tr>
<td valign="top">$<?php echo($budget_summary->getColumnVal("budgeted_amount")); ?></td>
<td valign="top">$<?php echo($budget_summary->getColumnVal("budgeted_balance")); ?></td>
<td valign="top"><?php echo($budget_summary->getColumnVal("program")); ?></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php
  $budget_summary->moveNext();
}
$budget_summary->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
?>
            </tbody>
          </table><?php } ?>
          <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the sql query:

```
<?php
$budget_summary = new WA_MySQLi_RS("budget_summary",$sa,0);
$budget_summary->setQuery("SELECT * from budget_summary where fund = ? and account = ? and deptID = ?");
$budget_summary->bindParam("i", "".$_POST['fund '] ."", "-1"); //colname
$budget_summary->bindParam("i", "".$_POST['account']  ."", "-1"); //colname2
$budget_summary->bindParam("i", "".$_POST['funding_department'] ."", "-1"); //colname3
$budget_summary->execute();
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form method="POST" id="frm" name="frm">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col mb-2">
    <label for="account">Account:</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="account2" id="account2" required>
      <option></option>
     <?php
while(!$accounts->atEnd()) { //dyn select
?>
                <option value="<?php echo($accounts->getColumnVal("account")); ?>"><?php echo($accounts->getColumnVal("account")); ?>: <?php echo($accounts->getColumnVal("description")); ?></option>
                <?php
  $accounts->moveNext();
} //dyn select
$accounts->moveFirst();
?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col mb-2">
    <label for="fund">Fund:</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="fund2" id="fund2" required>
      <option></option>
     <?php
while(!$funds->atEnd()) { //dyn select
?>
                <option value="<?php echo($funds->getColumnVal("fundID")); ?>"><?php echo($funds->getColumnVal("fundID")); ?>: <?php echo($funds->getColumnVal("fund")); ?></option>
                <?php
  $funds->moveNext();
} //dyn select
$funds->moveFirst();
?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col mb-2"> 
            <label for="fund">Department ID#:</label>
             <input type="text" name="funding_department2" id="funding_department2" class="form-control input-md" autocomplete="off" value="" required>
    </div></div>
<button type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" class="btn-lg btn-info">Search</button>   
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frm').on('submit', function(e){
      $('#myLargeModalLabel').modal('show');
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Any tips would be appreciated on how to make this happen. I have been trying for days to figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you insert the data directly into the databse or into fields in your modal?

Try the following:

Insert Data into the fields (if you have them), than try to print them with either PHP or Java to see if you recieve any values.

If you recieve them with java and can print them with java:

Your client gets the data that you insert but PHP is the serverside of you programm. You need to get the data with a php-statement.

Comment: No, there is no insert. Just a query. It is using the data entered into the form fields that haven't been submitted yet to query the database with and then display the data in the modal.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to acces data from a jQuery in PHP. You are trying to $GET the data in the modal but you don't give them to the modals. Show me your form and i can show you how to do this

Comment: I have added the form code to the posting. Thanks

Comment: What does the Method submit_handler() do?

Comment: <script>
function submit_handler() {
  console.log("modal opened"); //send with ajax?
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  event.preventDefault();
}

function submitform() {
  $('#new_group').submit();
}
</script>

Comment: It opens the modal using a form submit button.

Comment: I have updated my post with a new version of code but, it is still not working. The modal won't even open.

Comment: I got the modal to open now but, I still can't get the form post data to be used in the query and show in the modal. Any advice?

Comment: You should not do this with $POST this is a $GET request

Comment: So, I changed the form action to GET and it still didn't work.

Comment: Sorry for not replying i will show you what i mean in a minute or two if you haven't figured it out

Comment: Thanks so much. I still haven't figured this out. :)

Comment: Hi Stephan. Just checking in to see if you can still help me with this. Thanks so much!